Can I decompose a tensor valued one form $\boldsymbol{T}^{\ \mu}{}_{\nu}$ into symmetric traceless, trace, and anti-symmetric?
As mentioned above, I want to see if a (1,1) can be decomposed? we have a metric to work with. Personally I think we can. For example decomposing the tensor $T^{\mu}{}_{\nu}$ by first lowering or raising we get $g^{\mu \sigma}T_{\sigma \nu}$, which we then can decompose into symmetric and anti-symmetric
\begin{equation}
= g^{\mu \sigma} (T_{(\sigma \nu)} + T_{[\sigma \nu]}) 
\end{equation}
The symmetric can be decomposed into trace and traceless
\begin{equation}
= g^{\mu \sigma} (T_{(\sigma \nu)} +\frac{1}{4}T^{\lambda}{}_{\lambda}g_{\sigma \nu} -\frac{1}{4}T^{\lambda}{}_{\lambda} g_{\sigma \nu} + T_{[\sigma \nu]})
\end{equation}
Then we can re-insert the metric to get our preferred result
\begin{equation}
=\overset{traceless~symmetric}{T^{\mu}{}_{\nu}} +\frac{\delta^{\mu}{}_{\nu}}{4}T^{\lambda}{}_{\lambda} + \overset{anti-symmetric}{T^{\mu}{}_{\nu}}
\end{equation}
Does this work? if yes, does it even work if the tensor is tensor valued one form?
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{T}^{\ \mu}{}_{\nu} = {T}^{\mu}{}_{\nu \rho} \boldsymbol{d}x^{\rho}
\end{equation}
Thank you

First note that your question is really one about tensors on a vector space (e.g., the tangent space at a point on a manifold). If you assume there is an inner product on the vector space (e.g., a Riemannian metric), then what you say is correct. But if there is no inner product (e.g., the tangent space of a manifold without a Rienannian metric), then a $(1,1)$-tensor can be decomposed only into a scale multiple of the identity plus a traceless tensor.

Thank you @Deane for your answer. Now if I have a non-tensorial one-form, like the connection, can I also decompose it in the vector space into the same decomposition? Assuming I have a metric on that space? Also, could you help me find a citation to that decomposition?

Could you try to make precise what you mean by a traceless or symmetric non-tensorial firm?

@Deane, If we consider the
$\mathbf{T}^{\mu}{}_{\nu}$written above as the non-tensorial form, I am lead to think, leaving the anti-symmetric out, it would be the following:
$$=\overset{trace-less}{\mathbf{T}^{\ \mu}{}{\nu}} + \frac{1}{4}\delta^{\mu}{}{\nu} \overset{trace}{\mathbf{T}^{\ \lambda}{}_{\lambda}}$$
which would be equal to
$$
=\overset{trace-less}{\boldsymbol{T}^{\ \mu}{}{\nu }}+ \frac{1}{4}\delta^{\mu}{}{\nu} \overset{trace}{\boldsymbol{\phi}}
$$
and $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ would be a one-form.

Where we would be able to expand $\boldsymbol{\phi}$ as a one form
$$
= \overset{trace-less}{{T}^{\ \mu}{}{\nu \rho}}\mathbf{d}x^{\rho} + \frac{1}{4}\delta^{\mu}{}{\nu} \overset{trace}{\mathbf{\phi}_{\rho}}\mathbf{d}x^{\rho}
$$
Would that work? Where $\mathbf{T}$ is a non-tensor?

Since the connection is not a tensor, this decomposition would depend on the coordinates used.

Thank you @Deane. Yes, but would that mean for such a decomposition? In general relativity the two lower indices of the connection were decomposed into symmetric and anti-symmetric, even though the connection is not a tensor
$$\Gamma^{\rho}{}{\mu \nu} = \Gamma^{\rho}{}{(\mu \nu)} +\Gamma^{\rho}{}{[\mu \nu]}$$
I am trying to decompose some tensor valued one-form into the connection one-form $\mathbf{\Gamma}^{\rho}{}{\mu}$ and a trace one form $\mathbf{\phi}$.
